# Get foreground from AdobeLabsUXMagicSelectionView (Adobe Creative SDK)

Tags: ios, uiimage, core-graphics, cgimage, adobecreativesdk

I'm trying to use [AdobeLabsUXMagicSelectionView](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/ios/#/Classes/AdobeLabsUXMagicSelectionView.html) and I'm facing with 2 problems. I wanna "cut" the selected area (foreground) using these 2 methods:

Method 1) `getForeground:andMatte:` It doesn't give me the correct foreground. When I select an area and call `getForeground:andMatte` I gives me foreground and background (mixed).

Selecting dog's face
[image]

Cutting dog's face
[image]

Documentation says:

> Alternatively, if you don’t need to process the underlying bitmap
>   directly, and intend to use the results as inputs to CoreGraphics or
>   CoreImage, you can call:

Method 2) After this I'm trying to "cut" as the documentation does

```
extension AdobeLabsUXMagicSelectionView {

    func foregroundCGImage() -> CGImage {
        let w = size_t(self.image.size.width)
        let h = size_t(self.image.size.height)
        let data = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(malloc(4 * w * h * sizeof(UInt8)))
        self.readForegroundAndMatteIntoBuffer(data)

        for var i = 0; i < 4 * w * h; i += 4 {
            let alpha: UInt8 = UInt8(data[i + 3]) / 255
            data[i] *= alpha
            data[i + 1] *= alpha
            data[i + 2] *= alpha
        }

        let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.NoneSkipLast.rawValue)
        let ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, w, h, 8, 4 * w, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), bitmapInfo.rawValue)
        let imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx)!

        return imageRef
    }

}
```

But it only paints (black) the non-selected portion (background) of the image.

Anyone can help? What I want is get a final image of selected area.

**UPDATE:**

As @DonWoodward said I've create this Cattegory:

```
@implementation AdobeLabsUXMagicSelectionView (Foreground)

- (UIImage *)getForeground {
    // show the results
    // first create a UIImage of just the foreground bits per the documentation in AdobeLabsUXMagicSelectionView.h
    size_t w = self.image.size.width;
    size_t h = self.image.size.height;

    uint8_t *data = (uint8_t *)malloc(4*w*h*sizeof(uint8_t));
    [self readForegroundAndMatteIntoBuffer:data];

    // Paint the non-selected portion of the image black
    for (int i = 0; i < 4*w*h; i += 4) {
        float alpha = (float)data[i + 3] / 255;
        data[i    ] *= alpha;
        data[i + 1] *= alpha;
        data[i + 2] *= alpha;
    }
    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, w, h, 8, 4*w, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
    UIImage * foregroundBits = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    return foregroundBits;
}

@end
```

But the result has a lot of black pixel around the "foreground".

[image]
[image]

What I need? Get a "clean" foreground (selected area without black pixels) to put over an UIImageView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you're premultiplying the RGB channels by your alpha channel, which implies that you would want to use `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast` when creating your context, as in:

```c
// Paint the non-selected portion of the image black
for (int i = 0; i < 4*w*h; i += 4)
{
    float alpha = (float)data[i + 3] / 255;
    data[i    ] *= alpha;
    data[i + 1] *= alpha;
    data[i + 2] *= alpha;
}
CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, w, h, 8, 4*w, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
UIImage * foregroundBits = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

More information can be found in the [CGImage docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGImageAlphaInfo)

Also, you could also try using `CGImageCreateWithMask` with the output of

```
- (void)getForeground:(UIImage **)foregroundImage andMatte:(UIImage **)matteImage
```

as described in the [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-CJBHIJEB)

```
UIImage *fg;
UIImage *matte;

[_magicSelectionView getForeground:&fg andMatte:&matte];

CGImageRef mattedForeground = CGImageCreateWithMask(fg.CGImage, matte.CGImage);
UIImage *foregroundBits = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:mattedForeground];

// show the results
_resultsView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, VIEW_Y_OFFSET, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height-VIEW_Y_OFFSET)];
_resultsView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[_resultsView setImage: foregroundBits];
[self.view addSubview: _resultsView];
```

If neither of these works, it's possible there might be some issues with the configuration of the `UIImageViews` being used to render the results, but without that code it's hard to say.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that your scale factor is of type `uint8_t` and so you're clipping the scale factor to zero.  Make it a float and it should work.  Here's the code from MagicPuppy (in objective c) that does it:

```
    // show the results
    // first create a UIImage of just the foreground bits per the documentation in AdobeLabsUXMagicSelectionView.h
    size_t w = _magicSelectionView.image.size.width;
    size_t h = _magicSelectionView.image.size.height;

    uint8_t *data = (uint8_t *)malloc(4*w*h*sizeof(uint8_t));
    [_magicSelectionView readForegroundAndMatteIntoBuffer:data];

    // Paint the non-selected portion of the image black
    for (int i = 0; i < 4*w*h; i += 4)
    {
        float alpha = (float)data[i + 3] / 255;
        data[i    ] *= alpha;
        data[i + 1] *= alpha;
        data[i + 2] *= alpha;
    }
    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, w, h, 8, 4*w, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
    UIImage * foregroundBits = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    // show the results
    _resultsView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, VIEW_Y_OFFSET, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height-VIEW_Y_OFFSET)];
    _resultsView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [_resultsView setImage: foregroundBits];
    [self.view addSubview: _resultsView];
```